# Opening dialer app and then placing phone number

Tags: android, android-intent, android-dialer

I already know how to open a dialer app on Android using an Intent but my problem is how the number is displayed. An example of a phone number format I would like to display on the dialer app is (00) 000 0000. But when it is displayed in the dialer app it shows up as (000) 000-000. Is there any way to display the number in the dialer app exactly how the formatted phone number is returned by Google Places API?

Answer (score 0):

No.  The dialer app is a separate app.  There's no way to control what it displays.  There's no way to even assure it displays the number at all-  it could literally be any app the user/the oem wants it to be.  All you know for sure is that it claims it can make a call.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You can only send the number to the dial intent, but it's up to the dialer to show it. It can vary on each device, app or version. For example, my dialer app shows it like `00 0000000`